# Apparent error in Matlab's perms function

Tags: matlab, math, permutation, discrete-mathematics, elementary-functions

```
 p = perms([0:2])
```

p =

```
 2     1     0
 2     0     1
 1     2     0
 1     0     2
 0     1     2
 0     2     1
```

[This function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) is supposed to display the permutations of a vector in reverse lexicographical order. Hence, I would expect the last row of this output to contain the elements `0 1 2`; however, it contains `0 2 1`. The other rows are displayed correctly.

In short, the order of the last two rows are interchanged. What is going on here?

Comment: No offense but is this a question?

Comment: The [example on Mathworks' website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) strangely does the same thing

Comment: @Benoit_11 I have edited it according to what I think the OP is trying to ask. Siva, if my edit does not accurately reflect your question, please edit again to clarify.

Comment: I have referenced the example on Mathworks website, which also seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be a bug. Good catch! But probably a bug in the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html), rather than in the function.

If you type `open perms` to see the source code, you'll see the following description in the first lines:

```
%PERMS  All possible permutations.
%   PERMS(1:N), or PERMS(V) where V is a vector of length N, creates a
%   matrix with N! rows and N columns containing all possible
%   permutations of the N elements.
%
%   This function is only practical for situations where N is less
%   than about 10 (for N=11, the output takes over 3 gigabytes).
%
%   Class support for input V:
%      float: double, single
%      integer: uint8, int8, uint16, int16, uint32, int32, uint64, int64
%      logical, char
```

in which no reference is made to reverse lexicographical order.

The actual job is done by the recursive, local function `permsr`. If you look at its code, it's not obvious at first how it works (as usual with recursion), but the line

```
t(t == i) = n
```

gives a clue that no particular order is sought in the result.

If you try a larger vector you'll see discrepancies from reverse lexicographical order in more rows:

```
>> perms(0:3)
ans =
     3     2     1     0
     3     2     0     1
     3     1     2     0
     3     1     0     2
     3     0     1     2
     3     0     2     1   %// here. Affects cols 1 and 2
     2     3     1     0
     2     3     0     1
     2     1     3     0
     2     1     0     3
     2     0     1     3
     2     0     3     1   %// here. Affects cols 1 and 2
     1     2     3     0
     1     2     0     3
     1     3     2     0   %// here. Affects cols 2 and 3
     ...
```

In summary, the function seems to have been designed without regard to any order. It is the documentation which is probably wrong in claiming that order.

Comment: If that was the case, then how can i sort the answers in lexicographical order.

Comment: @LuisMendo - What Siva really means is to thank you for being so diligent in your efforts and that he will accept your answer very soon in the near future.

Comment: @LuisMendo - BTW, awesome detective work.  You already had my upvote.

Comment: @rayryeng Hahaha. Thank you for your comment. I'm literally laughing out loud. I agree that Siva's comment was a bit terse :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I've made a chat room for us MATLAB folks: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab - I think it's about time!